# Access SharePoint Site via File Explorer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, fileserver

IS it Possible to access a SharePoint site via file Explorer as in mapping it as a network folder as i have followed a bits i have seen online to no success.

i know you can sync document library to OneDrive but I want to access SharePoint as if I was still accessing the old fileserver if that makes sense

Thanks

Comment: Please move this question to [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to add the whole SharePoint site with one click to file explorer. Specific Document Libraries will be added to your file explorer. To sync the whole SharePoint site and it to file explorer you need to separately add all site libraries.